# Title in my iOS app is shifted to the left from the center

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

Title in my application is shifted to the left from the center on iPhone, although when I open my app in the browser heading straight down the middle. How to fix it?
here mine html code

`<div data-view="Moobile.ScrollView" class="component-testpage-view">
    <div data-role="navigation-bar" class="center">
         <div data-role="button" data-name="back-button" data-style="back">
          <div class="back"></div>
       </div>
        <div data-role="title" class="bar-center">Найдено</div>
        <div data-role="button" data-name="favorite" class="bar-right"> 
            <div class="best"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-name="category-field">
        <div class="activity-text">Загрузка</div> 
        <div data-role="activity-indicator" data-name="activity-indicator" class="activity-indicator active"></div>
    </div>
</div>`

mine css code `/* main-background
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.main-background {-webkit-transition: all 0.5s; -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px); top: 44px;}
.button-top {/*overflow: auto; margin-top: -10px;*/}
.in-right {position: relative; height: 55px;}

.bar.navigation-bar.center .bar-item .bar-title-wrapper {pointer-events: none;}
.bar.navigation-bar.center .bar-item .bar-title {height: 44px; line-height: 44px; left: 0px; position: absolute;}`

[image]

Comment: We need the css code for the styles given.

Comment: @JoseMagana, i'm added css code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing/removing the css that says `left:0px`? This is basically putting it as far left in its div as possible.

Comment: I tried to change it but to the problem that did not lead

Comment: Try to remove `left: 0px; position: absolute;`

Comment: You should also check the div positioning itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I would override that particular line of html and write it after the main CSS. Than use the normal way of centering text in a div.

To center text in a div

```
.bar-center {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 70%;

}
```